# How to Execute a command or process in Console application using C#

Tags: c#, console-application, spss

I am developing one console application that will convert all spss (.sav) files to .csv files. For this I created a SPSS job (spssJob1.spj) manually (using one .sps file) and I am iterating through all the input files (all .sav files) and trying to run that job by updating the input and output path in the .sps file (text.sps). But I don't know how to call that job execution command from my app.

Currently, the command is:

```
stats C:\Users\10522\Desktop\spssJob1.spj -production
```

and this should be executed from

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22
```

because this stats command will be available only in this directory.

So in my app I need to call this process from this path; I am able to call one `.exe` file by using my app but I don't know how to call one command form a specific directory.

This is my code:

```
// getting all spss files from the from the input path 
FileInfo[] Files = new DirectoryInfo("D:\Input").GetFiles("*.sav");

// looping each files and calling the job
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{ 
    if (file.Name != "")
    {
        // updating the text.sps file for each job                       
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\Input\text.sps", string.Empty);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\Input\text.sps", (Content for the file));

        // calling the process
        var p = new Process();
        // this code will work fine simply calling one exe
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo((@"D:\Input\temp.exe"), "-n")
        // instead of this I need to call something like this
        // stats C:\Users\10522\Desktop\spssJob1.spj -production from this 
        // path C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22 
        {
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("stats");
        pi.Arguments = @"C:\Users\10522\Desktop\spssJob1.spj -production";
        pi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22";
        pi.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.Start(pi);
```

you can do this by altering ProcessStartInfo's properties.

Not sure what stats is, if its an exe then you can specify the full exe path and just omit working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, stats is a command to execute a particular job using SPSS

Comment: I added some additional things to it and am posting the answer down.thank u very much for your support.

Comment: I commented  this line "pi.UseShellExecute = false;" because it showing some issue when i am running in same console,, and i added " p.WaitForExit();" because SPSS needed licence for executing each job so if i execute parallel it won't generate the output file

Answer (score 0):

```
  var p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("stats")
                    {
                        //UseShellExecute = false,
                        Arguments= @"C:\Users\10522\Desktop\spssJob1.spj -production",
                        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22",
                    };
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
```